# Please explain below SOQL query

Tags: soql

I have seen many people writing this kind of query:

```
Account acc = [select Id,name from account where Id=:someId].Name;
```

can any one please explain me what is the use of ".Name" here. What it do and how it is different from other soql query.

Thanks

Comment: the above statement would thrown an error `Illegal assignment from String to Account`

Comment: are you referring this `String acc = [select Id,name from account where Id=:someId].Name;` ?

Comment: this query is just an example. I want to know what is the use of .Name and how it is different from normal query where we don't use .Name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code assigns the Account instance to variable acc, which can be referenced later on in your code.

`Account acc = [select Id,name from account where Id=:someId];`

But what if you need to just use the `Account`'s field (in your case `Name`) alone, and do not want to store the account instance(which is not needed).Then you could do this:

```
String accName = [select Id,name from account where Id=:someId].Name;
```

Above is an short form of:

```
Account acc = [select Id,name from account where Id=:someId];
String accName = acc.Name;
```